# In Symfony2 (v2.3.4) - FOSUserBundle conflicts with Controller Route generated by CRUD

Tags: symfony, routes, crud, fosuserbundle

First of all im still learning so don't be angry at me for asking this question (and for my English - im trying my best).

Im going through book tutorial which is written for Symfony 2.0.10, but for each exercise i'm using newest Symfony 2.3.4 project, solving out eventually changes (learning that way) with a good results but finally i'm stuck.

The problem is that the point of exercise is to "make an app which is accessible only for logged users" using FOSUserBundle and CRUD panel. (without registering and all that unnecessary stuff)

Like in the tutorial, i created a bundle (My/BackendBundle), deleted its controller and views, then i  created a entity called MyBackendBundle:Mountain and populate db with my data. Next i created CRUD panel for entity i've created before, so the new controller appears wth all those "show", "new" "edit" etc methods. The **important** thing is that generated controller class (which is named MountainController because of "MyBackendBundle:Mountain" entity) have this @Routing annotation before class:

```
/**
 * Mountain controller.
 * 
 * @Route("/mountain")
 */
class MountainController extends Controller
{
...
```

But tutorial ordered to **delete this annotation** in order to use simply Project/web/ address instead of Project/web/mountain. so i did.

Then i created and admin account and change my routing.yml to looks like this:

routing.yml

```
my_backend:
    resource: "@MyBackendBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

fos_user_security:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/security.xml"
```

Next step of tut is to modify the security.yml to looks like this:

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: sha512

    #role_hierarchy:
    #    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    #    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username
            #id: fos_user.user_manager

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_provider: form.csrf_provider

                # the user is redirected here when he/she needs to login
                login_path:                     /login

                # if true, forward the user to the login form instead of redirecting
                use_forward:                    false

                # submit the login form here
                check_path:                     /login_check

                # by default, the login form *must* be a POST, not a GET
                post_only:                      true
                #remember_me:    false

                # login success redirecting options (read further below)
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path:            /
                target_path_parameter:          _target_path
                use_referer:                    false

                # login failure redirecting options (read further below)
                failure_path:                   null
                failure_forward:                false

                # field names for the username and password fields
                username_parameter:             _username
                password_parameter:             _password

                # csrf token options
                csrf_parameter:                 _csrf_token
                intention:                      authenticate

            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Next steps is about to add logout link to base.html.twig and to override the login page, but this probably doesn't matter because problems already started. When i try to run my app i've got **Unable to find Mountain entity.** exception. which is pointed to this function in MountainController:

```
/**
     * Finds and displays a Mountain entity.
     *
     * @Route("/{id}", name="mountain_show")
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function showAction($id)
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $entity = $em->getRepository('MyBackendBundle:Mountain')->find($id);

        if (!$entity) {
            throw $this->createNotFoundException('Unable to find Mountain entity.');
        }

        $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($id);

        return array(
            'entity'      => $entity,
            'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
        );
    }
```

I'm almost sure it has something to do with the **@Route("/{id}", name="mountain_show")** annotation which is generated by CRUD because the "login_path" from security.yml which is "/login" fits to @Route pattern of showAction. So the action instead of getting the id of record to show (which should be a number), receives an text or i don't know what, and tries to find id with negative results.

Ps. The example from tutorial (on Symfony 2.0.10) working because the "showAction" generated by CRUD has route:  `@Route("/{id}/show", name="mountain_show")` 
which isn't conflicts.

So if there is anybody who can help me with this i will be very appreciated.

If there is any more info i can give to better explain my problem just say. Regards. KB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

symfony's routing will try to match the **first** matching route found ... in your case the other controller's annotation routes are configured before/above FOSUserBundle's ones ... Therefore symfony will first try to match `/{id}` and then `/login`.

just move FOSUserBundle's routes **before** your other controller's route in your configuration to fix this issue.

Comment: Thank You for the answer, you have the point.  
I knew about that the order of Routes is important  
but i thought that this concerns only the "acces_control"  
section of security.yml. I made changes in routing.yml
and now "my_backend" is after the "fos_user_security".
Now login screen appear but unfortunately, after i log in i've got "Acces Denied" exception. huh